# Separation of Two Sets

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

The separation of two sets $K_{1}, K_{2}$ is given by $sep(K_{1},K_{2}) = \inf_{x \in K_{1}, y \in K_{2}}||x-y||$. Let $K$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. A subset $K_{1}$ of $K$ is said to be a $\textit{part} $ of $K$ if it is a proper subset of $K$ and the separation of $K_{1}$ and $K\setminus K_{1}$ is positive.

I'm given the set $K =\{0\} \cup \{2^{-n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and asked to find which subsets of $K$ are parts of $K$.

The reason I bring this question here is because I think I'm either interpreting it wrong or it's a trick question. The euclidean norm yields a value always greater than equal to zero, so for a subset $K_{1}$ to be a part it must have $sep(K_{1},K\setminus K_{1}) = 0$. For as long as I stare at the question I continue to think that the answer is ALL the proper subsets of $K$. Sure, there are subsets for which we can make the separation of it and its complement in $K$ as close to zero as we like, but it never actually reaches zero and so always remains positive. Is this correct?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, $\left\{\frac{1}{2} \right\}$ has separation $\frac{1}{4}$ from the rest of $K$; but $\{0\}$ has separation $0$ from the rest of $K$. So the answer isn't "all proper subsets".

Comment: I really don't know why I didn't notice that before, it would now seem that any proper subset not containing $\{0\}$ is the answer, since then if we have a subset with smallest element $2^{-n}$ it has separation $2^{-(n+1)} \neq 0$?

Comment: That assumes there is a smallest element of this subset, but you're correct in the case that the subset has a smallest element which is not $0$.

Comment: Also, if it contains $0$, why must it not be a part of $K$? (Hint: it can be a part of $K$.)

Comment: Having thought about it, the set $\{0\} \cup \{2^{-k} \mid k \geq 2\}$ would also be a part of $K$. Or rather, $\{0\} \cup \{2^{-n} \mid n \geq k\}$ with $k \geq 2$.

Comment: After taking a break I think I might have an answer that covers all of the parts. The set $\{2^{-n} \mid n \in S\}$ where $S$ is any finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is a part (and any subsets of this set). Also, the set $\{0\} \cup \{2^{-n} \mid n \geq k\} \cup S$ where $k \geq 2$ and $S$ is any proper subset of $\{2^{-n} \mid n < k\}$ is a part (and any subsets of this set). I believe this covers all the possible forms a subset could take in this case. Thoughts?

Comment: In order that sep$(K_1,K$ \ $K_1)\ne 0$ it is necessary that $0\not \in \bar K_1$ or $0\not \in \overline {K\backslash K_1}$. This requires that $K_1$ is finite, and does not contain $0$ or that $K$  \  $K_1$ is finite and does not contain $0$. And this condition, along with $ K_1\ne K,$ turns out to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slicker way to give your answer from the comments: it's a part iff either:

- It contains $0$ and is infinite but not the entire set
- It doesn't contain $0$ and is finite but nonempty.

---

Suppose the set contains $0$.

- If it's finite, it's not a part: its complement contains arbitrarily small $2^{-n}$ so gets arbitrarily close to $0$.
- If it's infinite:

  - If it contains $\{2^{-n}: n \geq k \}$ for some $k$, it's a part iff it's not the entire set, because then the distance to its complement is at least $2^{-k}$.
  - If it doesn't contain a segment like that, then the complement gets arbitrarily close to $0$ which is in the set, so it's not a part.

Now suppose the set doesn't contain $0$.

- If it's finite and nonempty, it's definitely a part, since it has a smallest element $2^{-n}$, so the distance to the complement is $2^{-(n+1)}$.
- If it's infinite, it must get arbitrarily close to $0$, so it's not a part.

Comment: Very well explained, I have to say one of the major issues for me in tackling this question was figuring out and understanding all of the different cases.